# Xamarin: What does NotSupportedException mean

Tags: android, android-viewpager, layout-inflater

Hello I have an error saying

> Could not activate JNI Handle 0xee0002d (key_handle 0x433275a0) of Java type 'md57680b01dd7fcef12aedb1f5afcbe69ae/RemoteDrawableView' as managed type 'MightyMeeting.RemoteDrawableView'.

But this happened after work and running it at home. I have not done anything on the layout or the view itself. The application compile but it happen had runtime.

The line where the error happened is LayoutInflater.FromContext(...).Inflate() inside my custom PagerAdapter

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a custom view that xamarin cannot load. Try typing in it in lower case

If your custom view is named this way :

```
namespace MightyMeeting.Droid.CustomViews
{
     public class RemoteDrawableView : ImageView
     {
       /*your code here*/
     }
}
```

Then in axml you should try to call it like this

```
<mightymeeting.droid.customviews.remotedrawableview
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    etc/>
```

This may not be the solution, but i encountered it recently.

Also try updating Xamarin on your home computer